# JSON copy same property to child nodes

Tags: json, jackson, fasterxml

I have a POJO structure similar to below,

```
public class A {
    private int val1;
    private String createdBy;
    private B bObj;
    .
    .
    // Getters and setters plus more fields

}

public class B {
    private int val2;
    private String val3;
    private String createdBy;
    .
    .
    // Getters and setters plus more fields
}
```

Input JSON like this

```
{
    "createdBy": "user_1",
    "val1" : 1,
    "bObj" : {
        "val2" : 2,
        "val3" : "3",
        "createdBy" : "user_1"
    }
}
```

I want to reuse the **createdBy** from my root class **A** inside the **bObj** without having to have the client send the same value in child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Extend [BeanDeserializer](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/BeanDeserializer.java) call super in deserialize and then do all maniplations you need there. Register your Deserialzer with using SimpleModule.

I am not sure if there is any other direct way to do so.